# How to save user input to the CalendarDatePicker and load it the next time user opens the app

Tags: c#, save, uwp, reload

I want to save user input date and load it next time user re-launches my UWP app. AS far as I understand I should use IsolatedStorage. But don't know how; Although I have added "using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;" directive to my program, I still get below error when I write this line of code:

```
var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Error:

> CS0103  The name 'IsolatedStorageSettings' does not exist in the
>   current context.

Any idea how to get it work?

Comment: Are you sure IsolatedStorageSettings exists in UWP? I think it is only in Silvelight for Windows Phone, but I'm not certain

Answer (score 0):

In *UWP* you don't have *IsolatedStorageSettings* class, use [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) instead:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["yourSetting"] = "Value"; // save setting
string savedValue = (string)localSettings.Values["yourSetting"]; // get saved data
```

For more help about saving data in app, take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx) - especially pay attention to what type of values can be saved there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Romasz!